# How to implement search in PaginatedDataTable Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, datatable, flutter-web, searchable

Hi I have a PaginatedDataTable and right now I would like to make it searchable so when I type some keyword it would show the data according to the keyword that users type... I have been searching some articles about it, but I didn't find yet... anyone knows some tutorials or articles or examples about it?

Comment: So be the first who creates this tutorial. ;) What is the problem to create a `TextField` which takes a search and filter list which is used as source for PaginatedDataTable?

Answer (score -1):

```
dataList: _searchController.text == ""
      ? widget.dataList
      : searchList,
actions: [
      AnimatedSearchBar(
          width: 300,
          textController: _searchController,
          onSuffixTap: () {
            setState(() {
              _searchController.text = "";
            });
          }),)]
```

they are PaginatedDataTable properties

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     if (searchableItemList.length != 0 && widget.dataList.length != 0) {
      _searchController.addListener(() {
        setState(() {
          searchList = dataList
        .where((element) => element
                .name
                .toLowerCase()
                .contains(controller.text.toLowerCase()))
        .toList();;
        });
      });
    }}
```

Comment: Hey, please take a moment to read [How to write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and you will realize that providing code without explanation is sometimes worse than not answering at all, please edit your answer accordingly, once you have read the provided document. Kind Regards!